# Disable Form Elements Using Event Capturing

Tags: javascript, events, forms

Is it possible to make form elements unusable without setting the `disabled` property for each element?

My idea was this:

```
container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}, true);
```

It behaves as intended for non form elements but it won't stop e.g. select elements from showing their options when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select will be open after the mousedown event so this is the event you have to stop.
http://jsfiddle.net/6K9Mj/